# Find the sum of the series.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I need to find the following sum:
$$\sum_{s=0}^{n+1}{(-1)}^{n-s}4^s\binom{n+s+1}{2s}$$

First I tried to simplify this:
$$\begin{split}
\sum_{s=0}^{n+1}{(-1)}^{n-s}4^s\binom{n+s+1}{2s}
 &= {(-1)}^n\sum_{s=0}^{n+1}{(-1)}^{s}2^{2s}\binom{n+s+1}{2s} \\
 &= \left[{(-1)}^{m-1}\sum_{s=0}^m{(-1)}^{s}x^{2s}\binom{m+s}{2s}\right](2)
\end{split}
$$

Now I reduced the problem to the following:
"Find generating function for the following sequence"
$$\sum_{s=0}^m{(-1)}^{s}x^{2s}\binom{m+s}{2s}$$

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this problem? Because if you [put it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B%28-1%29%5Es%2ax%5E%282s%29%2aBinom%28m%2bs,s%29,%7Bs,0,m%7D%5D) to the Wolfram|Alpha result is terryfing and I hope that generating function produced by wolfram is too generalized (for any values of x and m).

UPD: I put the wrong sequece to Wolfram|Alpha, here is the correct [one](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B%28-1%29%5Es%2ax%5E%282s%29%2aBinom%28m%2bs,2s%29,%7Bs,0,m%7D%5D).
So, Wolphram|Alpha says now, that:
$$\sum_{s=0}^m{(-1)}^{s}x^{2s}\binom{m+s}{2s} = \frac{2\cos\left((2m+1)\arcsin\left(\frac2x\right)\right)}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}$$
Unfortunately, it is undefined for $x=2$. While when we set $x=2$ for initial query (Sum[(-1)^s*2^(2s)*Binom(m+s,2s),{s,0,m}]) the answer is following:
$$\sum_{s=0}^m{(-1)}^{s}2^{2s}\binom{m+s}{2s} = {(-1)}^m(2m+1)$$
And I still wondering, how to prove that?

Comment: Isn't it this (http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e9poehact3s) what you wanted to put in Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: I can't copy your link. Here is the input for Wolfram|Alpha: Sum[(-1)^s*x^(2s)*Binom(m+s,s),{s,0,m}].

Comment: Why your Binom part has Binom(m+s,s) instead of Binom(m+s+1,2s)? And $(-1)^{s}$  instead of $(-1)^{m-s}$?

Comment: @karene, I see now. You put original sum to the wolfram. It looks simplier, but I do not know how to prove that the sum of the original sequence is equal to $-2n-3$.

Comment: @soul-of-kitchen There are many ways to prove this, but since it is homework, the reasonable first step would be to ask what methods you have recently learned.

Comment: @Phira I can derive generating functions from given basic generating functions like $(1+x)^n$, $\frac1{1-x}$, etc. And I can use mathematical induction. Unfortunately, when I am trying to apply mathematical induction in this case I have this: $S_{n-1} = \sum_{s=0}^{n}{(-1)}^{n+s-1}4^s\binom{n+s}{2s}=-2n-1$; $S_n = -S_{n-1}-4^{n+1} + \sum_{s=1}^n{(-1)}^{n+s}4^s\binom{n+s}{2s-1}$

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply generating functions, you should not usually replace a random constant in the sum with a variable (although in this particular case this works, too). You should call the whole sum $S_n$ and look at the generating function with coefficients $S_n$.

Comment: Generating function with coefficients $S_n=\sum_{s=0}^{n}{(-1)}^{n-s-1}4^s\binom{n+s}{2s}$ is following: $-\frac{x+1}{{(x-1)}^2}$. But how it will help me to find exact value of $S_n$?

Comment: @soul-of-kitchen Excellent, now you just have to re-expand $(1-x)^{-2}$ with binomial coefficients (or simply know/lookup the particular expansion).

Comment: @soul-of-kitchen Alternatively, since you know the desired result, you can try to get the generating function for ${(-1)}^m(2m+1)$ and compare.

Comment: Well, I know generating function, because I know that $S_n=\sum_{s=0}^{n+1}{(-1)}^{n-s}4^sC_{n+s+1}^{2s}=-2n-3$, but I can not prove that $S_n=-2n-3$.

Comment: @soul-of-kitchen Write down the generating function of the sequence with only $(-1)^m$, and of the sequence $m(-1)^m$  (interpret it as a derivative). Deduce the generating function of the right-hand side of your identity.

Comment: I know how to deduce generating function for $\sum_{s \ge 0} (-2n-3)x^n$. But it won't help me to get $S_n$.

Comment: @soul-of-kitchen If you find that the left-hand side and the right-hand side of your identity have the same generating function then you have proven the identity.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I can't deduce generating function for $S_n$, I know it only because Wolfram|Alpha knows it.

Comment: @soul-of-kitchen Have you tried writing down the generating functions, changing the order of the two sums, summing the inner sum and then the outer sum?

Comment: Yes, but I wasn't able to deduce $S_n$ in any way.

Comment: @soul-of-kitchen Would you write down in your question at which point you get stuck in the above procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$\sum_{q=0}^{n+1} (-1)^{n-q} 4^q {n+q+1\choose 2q}
= (-1)^n \sum_{q=0}^{n+1} (-1)^{q} 4^q {n+q+1\choose n+1-q}.$$

We use the integral
$${n+q+1\choose n+1-q} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{n+q+1}}{z^{n-q+2}} \; dz.$$

This has the property that it is zero when $q\gt n+1$ so we may extend
$q$ to infinity to get
$$\frac{(-1)^n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{n+1}}{z^{n+2}} 
\sum_{q\ge 0} (-1)^{q} 4^q (1+z)^q z^q\; dz.$$

This yields
$$\frac{(-1)^n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{n+1}}{z^{n+2}} 
\frac{1}{1+4(1+z)z} \; dz
\\ = \frac{(-1)^n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{n+1}}{z^{n+2}} 
\frac{1}{(2z+1)^2} \; dz.$$

Extracting the residue we get
$$(-1)^n \sum_{q=0}^{n+1} {n+1\choose n+1-q} \times 
(-1)^q \times (q+1) \times 2^q
\\ = (-1)^n \sum_{q=0}^{n+1} {n+1\choose q} \times 
(-1)^q \times (q+1) \times 2^q.$$

Now observe that
$$(x(1+x)^n)' = \sum_{r=0}^n {n\choose r} (r+1) x^r
= (1+x)^n + nx (1+x)^{n-1}.$$

This gives two components for the sum, the first is
$$(-1)^n (-1)^{n+1} = -1,$$
and the second is
$$(-1)^n \times (n+1) \times (-2) \times (-1)^{n}$$

for a final answer of
$$-1- 2(n+1) = -2n-3.$$